# How would I close the connection to the irc server?

Tags: php, bots, irc, mintty

I have made an IRC bot running on the MinTTY terminal emu and it is programmed in php.
How would I close the connection between the server and bot?
I've done it on my web version but this is a little different on MinTTY... Could I just use fclose($start); ?
Thanks in advance.
P.S; Below is a code snippet of how the bot connects:

`$socket = fsockopen("$server", $port);
fputs($socket,"USER $nick $nick $nick $nick :$nick\n");
fputs($socket,"NICK $nick\n");
fputs($socket,"JOIN ".$chan."\n");`

Comment: Please add some details to your question; as of now, it is too broad.

Comment: Details such as what, all I need to know is how to kill the connection.

Comment: details like how the connection was opened in the first place (relevant php code)

Comment: Done, added how the bot connects.

Comment: Sending `QUIT` should cause the server to hang up, no?

Comment: Why not just calling `fclose` like usual? As you seem to know that this usually works, why shouldn't it in this case?

Comment: Oh okay, I'll try fclose, but how would I close the connection traditionally in IRC?

Comment: FCLose does not work nor does doing `fputs($socket, "QUIT");